# Using Jquery how can I add a HTML element based on JSON result

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

This is currently what I have if my Json object returns true then I add class error_back to #message else add class success_back.  This works correctly, but now I want to add a button so  I tried this:

**Invalid Code**

```
 $('#message').append((data.error === true) ? 
 '<input type='submit' name='submit' class='button' id='submit_btn' value='Go back' />' : '' );
```

**Works correctly :**

```
 $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error_back' : 'success_back').text(data.msg);
```

What is the correct way to add a button?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the highlighted code, you will notice that it looks strange. You are using single quotes to wrap your string, but you're also using single quotes *within* the string.

Personally, I try to avoid constructing HTML strings as much as possible:

```
if (data.error) {
    $('<input />', {
        type: 'submit',
        name: 'submit',
        'class': 'button',  // `class` is a reserved keyword
        id: 'submit_btn',
        value: 'Go back'
    }).appendTo('#message');
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, please wrap the the `class` with  quotation marks.

Comment: @undefined: Oddly, the code works just fine as-is and doesn't throw any warnings or errors. It might be due to JS's somewhat strange object constructor. I'll have to see why.

Comment: Yes, ECMAScript5-based browsers allow using reserved words, but IE browsers.. :)

Comment: @undefined: Thanks, I'll add it in.

Answer (score 3):

There is a syntax error in your code, you should not nest the single quotes.

```
$('#message').append( data.error ? '<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Go back" />' : '' );
```

Comment: This gives no error , but it doesn't add the button, if data returns true.

Comment: @Edward What type of element is `#message`?

Answer (score 1):

That is invalid because of the **Quotes**  .. You are using **Single Quote '** to encase the string and also to encase the attributes.. So it will not interpret correctly.. To avoid that use **Double Quotes "** to fix it or need to escape the single Quotes..

```
$('#message').append(data.error  ? 
 "<input type='submit' name='submit' 
              class='button' id='submit_btn' value='Go back' />" : " " );
```

\OR **Escape the Quotes**

```
$('#message').append(data.error ? 
     '<input type=\'submit\' name=\'submit\' 
                  class=\'button\' id=\'submit_btn\' value=\'Go back\' />' : ' ' );
```